# AdminTask.createDatasource giving syntax error in Dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile, websphere-8

I am trying to create the oracle datasource in the docker container.

Refarance
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/timdp/entry/automating_application_installation_and_configuration_into_websphere_application_server46?lang=en

using below commands.

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.12-profile
RUN wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype NONE -c "AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry('-alias Oracle_User -user dbuser -password dbpwd')"
RUN wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype NONE -c "AdminTask.createJDBCProvider(['-scope' 'Node=DefaultNode01','Server=server1' '-databaseType' 'Oracle' '-providerType' 'Oracle JDBC Driver' '-implementationType' 'Connection pool data source' '-name' 'Oracle_JDBC_Driver_Provider' '-description' 'Oracle JDBC Driver' '-classpath' ['/opt/lib/ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.0.jar'] '-nativePath' '' ])"
RUN wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype NONE -c "AdminTask.createDatasource('Oracle_JDBC_Driver_Provider', '[-name MyDataSource -jndiName jndi/jndiname -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper -containerManagedPersistence true -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias DefaultNode01/Oracle_User -configureResourceProperties [[URL java.lang.String jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:48441/SID]]]')"
```

But getting below error

```
    The command '/bin/sh -c wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype NONE -c "AdminTask.createDatasource('Oracle_JDBC_Driver_Provider', '[-name MyDataSource -jndiName jndi/jndiname -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper -containerManagedPersistence true -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias DefaultNode01/Oracle_User -configureResourceProperties [[URL java.lang.String jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:48441/SID]]]')"' returned a non-zero code: 103 –
```

Comment: Unless you really have to use traditional WebSphere, I'd recommend using WebSphere Liberty, which is much better fit for Docker and has easier configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the syntax error is an unmatched ' character as the second to last character of the createDataSource command.  To correct this, you need to add another ' character just before `[-name MyDataSource`